# How ı can create class object by user input from another python file

Tags: python, oop, object, input

I have a file `a.py` with class to include, another file `b.py` with the main code. I want to create object by uer input in `b.py` file.
I'm new at programming and I am really stuck.

Here is instance

Here is the first file `a.py`

```
class Sell:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x,self.y=x,y
```

Here is the second file `b.py`

```
#b.py
from a import Sell
x=input()
y=input()
s=Sell(x,y)
```

I have a weird error:

```
Type error: İnit takes 1 argument but you gave 3 argument.
```

I really dont understand that init takes 1 argument,init(self,x,y)

İf someone help me ı can pray for his/her code works well in her/his project.

Comment: This worked nicely for me. Please try correcting the indentations and spellings, Especially change the spellings in the first file. I hope it will work!

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine when you fix indentation issues. The class functions and init method must be inside the class definition, which means they must be indented. Also `class` keyword is lowercase.

This is the correct version

`a.py`

```
class Sell:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x,self.y=x,y
```

and `b.py`

```
from a import Sell
x=input()
y=input()
s=Sell(x,y)
```

Comment: Your comment help me so much, ı paid attention that  

y is interger in my program

y=int(input())

so work it now

Thank you so much bro

Answer (score 0):

Error was that;
Type error: İnit takes 1 argument but you gave 3 argument.

İt is an type error so pay attention to strings and integers.

Whether you define it is integer and İf you give an integer, python think it is string.
That is why tell you that you gave 3 argument despite you gave 2 argument

a.py

```
class Sell:
def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x,self.y=x,y
```

and b.py

```
from a import Sell
x=input()
y=int(input()) # y was an integer input.
s=Sell(x,y)
```

İt works well now.